# How to not count blank pages in frontmatter of two-sided document

Tags: page-numbering, double-sided, front-matter

I'm writing a thesis using two-sided Book style, and in the frontmatter I would like to either be able to enter the page numbers on the pages manually or to alter the page counts to not count blank pages in the front matter.

To specify:

- frontpage (no number) - no probem
- blank
- Project description (i) - bo problem, i set count to 1
- blank
- Preface (ii) - but here it enter iii as the blank page counts.
  ... ect.

how do i fix this?

And please don't suggest changing style, as this is the last alterations of a 120 page thesis.
Hope you can help, and thank you for taking the time!

code sample:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\graphicspath{Figures/}  % Location of the graphics files (set up for graphics to be in PDF format)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec} %/Emilie. For fine titler
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge\thechapter.\hskip0.5em}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless} {0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
...packages
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter      % Begin Roman style (i, ii, iii, iv...) page numbering
%titlepage
\begin{titlepage}

\end{titlepage}

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\setstretch{1.3}  % It is better to have smaller font and larger line spacing than the other way round

% Define the page headers using the FancyHdr package and set up for one-sided printing
\fancyhead{}  % Clears all page headers and footers
%\rhead{\thepage}  % Sets the right side header to show the page number
%\lhead{}  % Clears the left side page header

\pagestyle{fancy}  % Finally, use the "fancy" page style to implement the FancyHdr headers

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{Chapters/A-description}% Project description 

\clearpage  
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\input{Chapters/A1-Resume} % Resume

\input{Chapters/A2-Abstract} % Abstract
```

and the thesis.cls file:

```
%% This is file `Thesis.cls', based on 'ECSthesis.cls', by Steve R. Gunn
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% Created by Steve R. Gunn, modified by Sunil Patel: www.sunilpatel.co.uk

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{Thesis}
          [2007/22/02 v1.0
   LaTeX document class]
\def\baseclass{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}
\def\@checkoptions#1#2{
  \edef\@curroptions{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}
  \@tempswafalse
  \@tfor\@this:=#2\do{
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\@this,}{,\@curroptions,}
    \ifin@ \@tempswatrue \@break@tfor \fi}
  \let\@this\@empty
  \if@tempswa \else \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{\baseclass}\fi
}
\@checkoptions{11pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\baseclass}
\newcommand\bhrule{\typeout{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}

\newcommand\Declaration[1]{
\btypeout{Declaration of Authorship}
\addtotoc{Declaration of Authorship}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
%\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\huge\bf Declaration of Authorship\par}\end{center}
%\vskip 60\p@
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null
%\cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand\btypeout[1]{\bhrule\typeout{\space #1}\bhrule}
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
\space \number\year}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb           { 1.5in}  % left margin
                    { 0.6in}  % top margin
                    { 1.0in}  % right margin
                    { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                    {  20pt}  % head height
                    {0.25in}  % head sep
                    {   9pt}  % foot height
                    { 0.3in}  % foot sep
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\topskip}{1\topskip \@plus 5\p@}
\doublehyphendemerits=10000       % No consecutive line hyphens.
\brokenpenalty=10000              % No broken words across columns/pages.
\widowpenalty=9999                % Almost no widows at bottom of page.
\clubpenalty=9999                 % Almost no orphans at top of page.
\interfootnotelinepenalty=9999    % Almost never break footnotes.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\btypeout{\thechapter\space #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{20pt}
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{Equation~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\cref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\sref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\aref}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.75}
\setcounter{topnumber}{9}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{9}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{20}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstpatch}
\lstset{captionpos=b,
    frame=tb,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keepspaces=true}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab} {
    language=Matlab,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.55,0.13}\em,
    stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.7,0,0} }
\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=false,
colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red},
pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
   \let\\\space
}
\renewcommand\maketitle{
  \btypeout{Title Page}
  \hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}
  \hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
  \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \null\vfil
    \vskip 60\p@
    \begin{center}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
       {\large\textbf{\UNIVNAME}\par}
      \vfill
      {\huge \bf \@title \par}
      \vfill
       {\LARGE by \par}
      \smallskip
      {\LARGE \authornames \par}
      \vfill
      {\large A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment for the \par}
      {\large degree of Chemical Engineering \par}
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\large at the \par}
      {\large \facname \par}
      {\large \deptname \par}
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\Large \@date \par}
      \bigskip
    \end{center}
   \par
    \@thanks
    \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
  \cleardoublepage
 }
\newenvironment{abstract}
{
 \btypeout{Abstract Page}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \null\vfil
  \begin{center}
   \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    {\huge{\textit{Abstract}} \par}
 \end{center}
}
{
  \vfil\vfil\vfil\null
  \cleardoublepage
}
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\newcounter{dummy}
\newcommand\addtotoc[1]{
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\btypeout{Table of Contents}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
\if@twocolumn
  \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
\else
  \@restonecolfalse
\fi
\chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{
       \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
\@starttoc{toc}
\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
\cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoffigures{
\btypeout{List of Figures}
\addtotoc{List of Figures}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
\if@twocolumn
  \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
\else
  \@restonecolfalse
\fi
\chapter*{\listfigurename
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}
          {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}
\@starttoc{lof}
\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
\cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoftables{
\btypeout{List of Tables}
\addtotoc{List of Tables}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
\if@twocolumn
  \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
\else
  \@restonecolfalse
\fi
\chapter*{\listtablename
  \@mkboth{
      \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}
\@starttoc{lot}
\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\newcommand\listsymbolname{Abbreviations}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofsymbols[2]{
\btypeout{\listsymbolname}
\addtotoc{\listsymbolname}
    \chapter*{\listsymbolname
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}{\MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listconstants{Physical Constants}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofconstants[2]{
\btypeout{\listconstants}
\addtotoc{\listconstants}
    \chapter*{\listconstants
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listconstants}{\MakeUppercase\listconstants}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listnomenclature{Symbols}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofnomenclature[2]{
\btypeout{\listnomenclature}
\addtotoc{\listnomenclature}
    \chapter*{\listnomenclature
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}{\MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\acknowledgements[1]{
\btypeout{Acknowledgements}
\addtotoc{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{center}{\huge{\textit{Acknowledgements}} \par}\end{center}
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null

}
\newcommand\dedicatory[1]{
\btypeout{Dedicatory}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\Large \sl #1}\end{center}
\vfil\null
\cleardoublepage
}
\renewcommand\backmatter{
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \addtotoc{\bibname}
  \btypeout{\bibname}
\@mainmatterfalse}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `Thesis.cls'.
```

Comment: Welcome, where can we find the class? Due to a lack of phantasy, there seem to be a thousand different classes called `Thesis.cls` out there.  So, pretty confusing.

Comment: @Johannes_B, i don't really know, so sorry as i'm just using a template in Sharelatex. But i will add it to the code.

Comment: Why don't you use `\setcounter` multiple times to adjust the pages manually? It's ugly, but for a few pages I wouldn't care. Maybe you could use variables to make it dynamic.

Comment: @luckyrumo, i tried, but it didn't reset the counter before the resume or the abstract ? even thougt i but \setcounter{page}{2} and \setcounter{page}{3} right before the input. Did i do it wrong?

Comment: @Emilie, have you tried to put it in the included file, below `\section` (or whatever you use) in there?

Comment: @luckyrumo, not yet as i was trying to make sure i could "reset" it back to normal after the frontmatter, how would i do that? 
But thank you for you code, i will try!

Comment: @Emilie: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "reset to normal".

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I'd do it with the `book` class:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{blankpages}
\def\cleardoublepage{%
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page
    \else
      \hbox{}\newpage\stepcounter{blankpages}%
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\@romannoblank}[1]{%
  \@roman{\numexpr#1-\value{blankpages}\relax}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\pagestyle{empty}

\vspace*{\fill}
{\centering\Huge The title\par}
\vspace*{\fill}

\cleardoublepage

\frontmatter\setcounter{blankpages}{0}\pagenumbering{romannoblank}

\chapter{Project description}

Here we describe our project

\chapter{Preface}

Some text

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}

\end{document}
```

The important thing is not modifying the value of the `page` counter, or the setting of pages would be spoiled.

I checked it also with `\documentclass{Thesis}`. Here's a picture of the Table of Contents page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't help necro-bumping. I have found egreg's answer very useful, with a small correction.

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{blankpages}
\def\cleardoublepage{%
    \clearpage
    \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page
    \else
    \hbox{}
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \newpage\stepcounter{blankpages}%
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi
    \fi
    \fi
}
\newcommand{\@romannoblank}[1]{%
    \@roman{\numexpr#1-\value{blankpages}\relax}%
}
\makeatother
```

`\thispagestyle{empty}` will come between `\hbox{}` and `\newpage`, otherwise the formatting of the empty pages was broken.

Hope it will be useful to others like me