# page numbering in frontmatter using double sided book class

Tags: double-sided, front-matter

I posted this qustion:

[How to not count blank pages in frontmatter of two-sided document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250761/how-to-not-count-blank-pages-in-frontmatter-of-two-sided-document)

But after i registered lost access to it...

The second answer by @egreg works very well in the frontmatter, but as soon as i start contents list, the automatic blank pages in double-sided shows header and footer, which is unwanted. how do i change that?

[image: the "blank" page after introduction before chaptor 1]

Comment: I used the answer provided by @egreg in the mentioned Question Thread (if you are able to then please mark his question as an answer it was very helpful) And then i simply added \clearpage \thispagestyle{empty}
after each chapter subseeding the frontmatter.

Comment: The staff can merge your accounts: use the [Contact Us](http://tex.stackexchange.com/contact) link.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: @DaiBowen just did, thanks for reminding me!

Comment: @EmilieValente you're welcome, are you able to add an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to this question?

Comment: @DaiBowen yes, but i used a weird class provided by my university, which caused quite some confusion in the question, so perhaps it would be better to simply delete this question, and as soon as my accounts are merged i will mark the used answer.