# Don't number blank pages in twoside option of memoir class

Tags: memoir, page-numbering

I have two versions of a lengthy document, one electronic and one for print. For the print version I am using the twoside option in memoir, and for the electronic, the oneside option. Since twoside introduces blank pages so that the chapters always start on a righthand page, the page numbering is slightly different between the two versions.

I would like both documents to have the same page numbering, i.e., I want to not number added blank pages.

I looked at the solution given here: [How to not count blank pages in frontmatter of two-sided document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250761/how-to-not-count-blank-pages-in-frontmatter-of-two-sided-document) but it did not work for me.

Here are the MWEs:

The twoside version produces 35 total pages, with one numbered blank page in between the two chapters:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

The oneside version produces 34 total pages, with no blank page in between the two chapters:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible, but a very bad idea. Per definiton, right hand pages are odd pages.

Comment: Do not do this. I would rather eliminate the blank pages. Pass `openany` as option to memoir

Comment: @MaxNoe what do you mean by pass openany as option to memoir?

Comment: `\documentclass[twoside, openany]{memoir}`

Comment: @MaxNoe I had the exact same question and your answer fixed the issue for me. Please post as an answer.

Comment: But here is an alternative solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275008/dont-count-empty-pages-in-twosideopenright-documents