# skip page count on blank pages in openright, twoside style

Tags: page-numbering, double-sided

How to skip page counting on blank pages created automatically by `openright` option? I have tried two solutions [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251343/dont-number-blank-pages-in-twoside-option-of-memoir-class), [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275008/dont-count-empty-pages-in-twosideopenright-documents), but none works for me.

Let's say **page 9** is the last page of chapter 1 and **page 10** is a blank page. The chapter 2 is starting with **page 11** on the right currently which is correct except for the page number which should be 10. I want to modify the page numbers only and not to remove the blank page or change the openright. Hope that it's clear now.

Comment: is what you want (1) to omit the printing of the page number, but keep the right-hand pages with odd numbers, or (2) to have right-handed pages after blank pages numbered consecutively (= even number) after an odd-numbered page preceding the blank?

Comment: Let's say page 9 is the last page of chapter 1 and page 10 is a blank page. The chapter 2 is starting with page 11 on the right now which is correct except for the page number which should be 10. I want to modify the page numbers only and not to remove the blank page or change the openright. Hope that it's clear now.

Comment: it's clear but rather weird. You would need to display a counter other than `page` as you need to keep the page counter with the real page numbers as latex chooses the left or right page style and whether a blank page is needed just by checking if the page counter is odd or even. Isn't the reader going to be very confused by such a numbering?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's how they have asked me to do.

Comment: Isn't politely saying no an option?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This is their thesis formatting.

Comment: they should fail the thesis for trying to confuse their examiner with wacky page numbering:-)

Comment: oh this is a duplicate of [the first link in the linked section on the right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275017/1090) which is already answered using the technique I suggested in the comment above (I used a different technique in the answer below). Note the comments in that other question again pointing out that this is not anything you would want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do this to change the parity of all the pagestyle related things, but I don't think I would ever do this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\let\zzoddsidemargin\oddsidemargin
\let\zzevensidemargin\evensidemargin
\let\zz@oddhead\@oddhead
\let\zz@evenhead\@evenhead
\let\zzcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage

\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\global\let\oddsidemargin\zzevensidemargin
\global\let\evensidemargin\zzoddsidemargin
\global\let\@oddhead\zz@evenhead
\global\let\@evenhead\zz@oddhead
\global\let\cleardoublepage\yycleardoublepage
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}

\def\yycleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page
\global\let\oddsidemargin\zzoddsidemargin
\global\let\evensidemargin\zzevensidemargin
\global\let\@oddhead\zz@oddhead
\global\let\@evenhead\zz@evenhead
\global\let\cleardoublepage\zzcleardoublepage
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}

\let\zzcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage

\begin{document}


\chapter{zzzzzz}
\section{Zzzz}
\subsection{Z Z}
abc

\newpage

zzzaiaiai


\chapter{zzzzz z}
\section{Zzz zz}
\subsection{Z zzZ}
abc xyz

\chapter{zzzzz zz}
\section{Zzz zzz}
\subsection{Z zzZzz}
abc xyz 123


\end{document}
```